# Como borrar fila en tableView con datos de CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

estoy haciendo una app que guarda información en `CoreData` y la muestra al usuario en una tabla. Agregué la función de eliminar filas al deslizar el dedo, pero estoy teniendo problemas para lograr el resultado.

Mi codigo es este:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print(results.count)
            let remove = results[indexPath.row]
            managedContext.delete(remove)

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
```

El error que me da es:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Entiendo que me dice que no se está borrando la información del arreglo que genera la tabla, pero según entiendo se debería de borrar en ésta línea `managedContext.delete(remove)`o me equivoco? ¿Cuál es el error?

Gracias

Comment: Si le indicas que vas a borrar una celda tienes que borrarla, de lo contrario da error. El results que es? estas sacando la información de ahi? xq de results no estas eliminando nada. Si trabajas con coredata no es necesario utilizar una array intermedio para obtener la información, lo sacas directamente de coreada

Comment: @Spidvmp results justamente es un array intermedio [NSManagedObject], lo utilizo para recibir el fetch de coreData al iniciar. ¿Cómo puedo trabajar directo CoreData sin el array intermedio? Gracias!

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usando NSFetchedResultsController, es una herramienta bastante poderosa y con la cual te puedes ahorrar mucho trabajo ya que responde automaticamente a los eventos que suceden en la base de datos: borrar, insertar, actualizar.

Aqui hay un tutorial sobre NSFetchedResultsController:
https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3

Y en esta seccion es donde abordan la eliminacion de datos:
https://cocoacasts.com/implement-the-nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-protocol-with-swift-3